# How to capture a comment's author then display in tooltip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, comments

I have a form attached to profiles where short comments can be submitted. I want to capture the author's name though so I can display it in a tooltip when hovering over the comment's body.

In my `create` method in the controller I have:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  @comment.save!
  redirect_to profile_path(@comment.profile)
end
```

Inside my migration:

```
t.timestamps
t.integer :profile_id
t.string :author_id
t.string :body
```

Profile model:

```
belongs_to :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
has_many :comments
```

Comment model:

```
belongs_to :profile
```

ProfilesController:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @profile = user.profile
  @superlative = @profile.superlatives.new
end
```

And my form:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :profile_id, :value => @profile.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :author_id, :value => "#{current_user.profile.first_name} #{current_user.profile.last_name}" %>
  <%= f.text_field :body %>
  <%= f.submit 'Add new' %>
<% end %>
```

I was thinking of linking the :author_id to current_user.profile.id and using that association to display :first_name and :last_name which are attributes of the profile. Or is there a simpler, better way?

**UPDATE:** I got it to display the name though I'm still curious if there's a better way.

Comment: Could you add your model definitions to the question?

Comment: Just added, thanks! I got it working by using a hidden field on the form and passing in a value. But if you think it could be better I'm curious. I'm still very much learning programming and Rails so I'm trying to pick up as many best practices as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure the hidden field is such a good idea. I could modify the form value before posting it and impersonate someone else. Unless you check that the value is equal to the current user, but why put a hidden field in that case?

Comment: @Benoit Great point. As a beginner to programming, I'm rarely considering all the possibilities. So I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks fine, but I'd store the `User` (or whatever class `current_user` returns) instead of the `Profile`:

In `app/models/comment.rb`:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "author_id"

  ... rest of the code ...

end
```

You then change your migration to:

```
t.integer :author_id
```

and your controller method to:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment].merge(:author_id => current_user.id))
  @comment.save!
  redirect_to profile_path(@comment.profile)
end
```

In your view (I used the `title` attribute do create a tooltip, but feel free to use whatever method you like):

```
<div class="comment" title="<%= @comment.author.profile.first_name %> <%= @comment.author.profile.last_name %>">
  <%= @comment.body %>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel like I'm almost there but something isn't right. Can you take a look at this question and let me know what you think? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290954/issues-getting-a-profile-to-update-and-show-newly-submitted-form-item

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

In your `routes.rb` create a nested resource for comments

```
resources :users do
  resources :comments
end
```

In your `User` model

```
class User
  has_many :comments
end
```

In your `Comment` model

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In your `CommentsController` in the `new` and `create` methods

```
@comment = User.find(params[:user_id]).comments.new(params[:comment])
```

So the comment automagically gets created as belonging to that User and you don't have to pass anything around.

Then, in your Comment view, you could just call its owners name

```
@comment.user.first_name
```