# Issues getting a profile to update and show newly submitted form item

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Following up on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279795/how-to-capture-a-comments-author-then-display-in-tooltip), I have a few issues to resolve before I have a comment form showing and submitting securely on my profile. I'm a beginner to programming so thinking across multiple controllers seems to have me lost.

What I'm doing is posting comments in a form, then listing them.

Background: The `_comment_form` and `_comment` reside as partials in the `Profile` about. (My next task is toggling from about to other Profile information, but that's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210146/opinion-needed-use-partials-or-not-in-structuring-profile-page) altogether.)

Using the help provided in my last question I feel like I'm almost there but am getting an error.

CreateComments migration:

```
t.integer :profile_id
t.integer :author_id
t.string :body
```

My Comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :author, :class_name =>"User", :foreign_key => "author_id"
end
```

CommentsController:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment].merge(:author_id => current_user.id))
  @comment.save!
  redirect_to profile_path(@comment.profile)
end
```

ProfilesController:

```
def create
  @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])
  if @profile.save
    redirect_to profile_path(@profile), :notice => 'User successfully added.'
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @profile = @user.profile
  @comment = @profile.comments.new
end
```

Comment partials inside Profile partial:

```
<div id="commentEntry">
  <%= render :partial => 'comment', :collection => @profile.comments %>
</div>
<div id="newitem">
  <%= render :partial => 'comment_form' %>
</div>
```

Routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  resources :profiles
end
resources :comments
```

_comment_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :body %>
  <%= f.submit 'Add new' %>
<% end %>
```

_comment.html.erb:

```
<li class="comment" title="<%= @comment.author.profile.first_name %> <%= @comment.author.profile.last_name %>">
  <%= @comment.body %>
</li>
```

**So, Issue #1:** Wrapping the `_comment.html.erb` in a loop `<% for @comment in @user.profile.comments %>` shows the profile but when I try and submit a new comment I get "Unknown action The action 'update' could not be found for CommentsController". If I take away the loop, the profile doesn't show and I get "NoMethodError in Profiles#show undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass". Can anyone help me out and explain what I'm doing wrong?

**Issue #2:** I created a sample comment in `rails console` and when I get the profile to show, the input field for comment :body repopulates with the comment's body. Any ideas on what could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short explanation of your problem:**

The `@comment` you're getting in your `_comment_form` partial is one that's already saved in your database, hence the call to the `update` action and the body that's already filled.

You're creating the new comment just fine with `@comment = @profile.comments.new` in your `show` action, but it gets overridden somewhere else.

You're mentioning that you wrapped the `_comment` render in a loop with `<% for @comment in @user.profile.comments %>`, the problem is most likely there.

**Fix:**

The only thing you should have to change is the `_comment` partial to (without the for loop that you added):

```
<li class="comment" title="<%= comment.author.profile.first_name %> <%= comment.author.profile.last_name %>">
  <%= comment.body %>
</li>
```

When you do the `render :partial => 'comment', :collection => @profile.comments`, rails is smart enough to loop over `@profile.comments` and give the `comment` (*not* `@comment`) variable to the partial.

**How to avoid this the next time:**

I'll give you two rules of thumb to avoid getting in this situation:

1. Try to name your variables more precisely. `@new_comment` would have been a better name for the variable to store the new comment. `@comment` is a bit ambigous as you've got a boatload of those in your view.
2. Avoid creating and modifying instance variables (`@` variables) in your views, try to do this only in your controller. I'll admit your particular case was a bit harder to detect because of the `<% for @comment in @user.profile.comments %>`. The view got its name for a good reason, it's only supposed to let you view the data you've defined in your controller.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the great troubleshoot explanation!

Comment: Thanks, hope it helped. A laconic solution can sometimes hurt more than help, I hope I've been clear enough.

Comment: Definitely. I think it's clear I need to hunker down on some Rails fundamentals.